# have it effect on performance when create ui in code?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I see that some developer create all UI in code . This is the advantage on performance?

they have one viewController in storyboard and create other viewControllers in code .

Comment: There's already a similar question here. Please refer to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704773/adding-views-storyboard-vs-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I also use the same approach. The view made by using this approach is that you can handle more logic in terms of changes to the view controller as showing keyboard events, hiding keyboard events and other such events which require the views to resize or change position. But the problem is that you cant inspect the view being rendered in real time