# Is it good practice, or at least not bad practice, to not use constraints

Tags: ios, constraints

As of late its occurred to me that the constraints I've been setting in storyboard simply aren't making my app look as great as it should across all phones.  I've found that coding in the frames of things with respect to the screen size has allowed me to get pixel perfect results much quicker.  Is this common practice, or am I not doing something right?  If using a few  constraints in conjunction with this technique is a more common practice, can anyone point me to a resource that describes the strategy I should be following?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Views. Storyboard VS. Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704773/adding-views-storyboard-vs-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of constraints, is that they define the relations between UI elements between each other - and that for all screen sizes and rotation. For instance you can align a bunch of controls and if one "master control" is moved or resized, all connected controls also change. And that also can be animated.

You can overwrite the some properties f your controls to work with the Apple Guidelines. Read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html) for details.